# Azure Devops Service Access restricted to Area

Tags: azure-devops, devops-services

I want to have a customer group which is only allowed to see and edit workitems in a certain area while not being able to see any other areas.

I created a Project, which contains two different areas. Additionally I created two Teams and two according groups (One that should be able access all and one "Customer Group" that should only be able to access the owned default area). Both groups are only members of Project Valid Users. Default paths are set to the according areas. I denied access for the Customer group to the other area. I explicitly allowed for the Customer group to access and edit their own areas workitems. Project Valid Users has permission View project-level information set to allow.

In this scenario the user in the customer group can only see/edit workitems in their area and also is not able the set the workitems to other areas. The problem is when editing an workitem in the restricted area the user can still see the other areas which is not wanted. (He is not able to set it though)

When i deny permission View project-level information of Project Valid Users although i have explicit allowed the Customer Group to the area without inheritance then the user isn't allowed to access anything. Removing the Customer group from Project Valid Users is not possible.

How can I achieve this "pure" Customer Area?
(A Project for the customer alone is no solution since projects amount is limited)

Answer (score 0):

To grant or restrict access to view, or edit work items, you should set **Area path** permission:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#area-path-object-level

> View work items in this node:
>
> If you set the View work items in this node to Deny, the user will not
>   be able to see any work items in this area node.

1. Choose (1) **Project Settings**, expand **Work** if needed, and choose (2) **Project configuration** and then (3) **Areas**.

[image]

2. Choose the ... context menu for the node you want to manage and select **Security**.

[image]

3. Select the group or team member, and then change the permission settings. If you don't see the group you want, try adding it first.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: It seems you missed the point. I achieved what you explained, still if you check the area path in an workitem you are allowed to edit, one can see all area paths including the restricted ones. You can't assign the workitem to them, still you are able to see them.

Comment: Do you mean you want to restrict the pick list of Area Path? Unfortunately, the pick list is not supported to be customized in Azure DevOps Service.